# Python sockets connection timeout problem

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a simple script that connects to the freenode IRC network (irc.freenode.net on port 6667) to periodically post information on a channel. To do this, I am employing Python sockets. This has worked fine in the past, however now I am experiencing a strange problem: the socket takes an incredibly long time to connect if it does at all (it occasionally times out). However, this only happens when the script is run from a file. When typed into the interpretor directly it works fine:

```
>>> import socket
>>> def f():
>>>    s = socket.socket()
>>>    print("Connecting")
>>>    s.connect(('irc.freenode.net', 6667))
>>>    print("Connected")
>>>    s.close()
>>> f()
```

The socket connects in about a second and everything is fine. However, if I put the following code in a file and run **python test.py**, it hangs on `s.connect` and occasionally times out:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
print("Connecting")
s.connect(('irc.freenode.net', 6667))
print("Connected")
s.close()
```

I have never had this problem before. This also occurs on other computers on my network (maybe it's  network problem?). I'm using Python 3.2. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Networks always have intermittent problems and your code will need to deal with them. I suggest two levels of action. First, use the `timeout=` argument on `socket.create_connection` to wait a bit longer before giving up. Then put the socket opening inside a `try` `except socket.timeout` pair and retry a couple of times, maybe sleeping a second or two between retries.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. The reason I think that this is a Python issue it that I can use an irc client (irssi) to connect just fine. I also ran a traceroute to irc.freenode.net and didn't find any major bottlenecks.

Comment: If you think that you have found a reproducible bug, then you should report it at http://bugs.python.org/